# Copy fonts between documents with PDFBox 2.0.8

Tags: fonts, pdfbox, text-extraction

For some reasons I need to extract content from one pdf and write it (ideally to be visually the same) to another.

Can anyone tell if it is possible, and point me to appropriate info?

I've made some progress already, so I'm currently most interested in next two questions:

1) Is there a possibility to full copy just a font info from one pdf document
to another with pdfbox?

2) What data do I need to extract from PDFont to create exactly the same font?

Comment: If you want the result to be *visually the same*, wouldn't it make more sense to copy the original page onto the target page and clip it down to the parts you are interested in?

Comment: @mkl I'm doing this to clean all possible vulnerabilities. I want to deconstruct document and then build a new one with the only visual elements that I think should be safe after extracting and recreating.

Comment: @mkl can you give me any advice about it? Thaks for any help

Comment: IMHO this is the same as your other question but asked differently.

Comment: *can you give me any advice about it?* - As generically as you put it, *"extract content from one pdf and write it (ideally to be visually the same) to another"*, you will eventually copy all vulnerabilities, too. Thus, the first thing to do should be to enumerate the concrete types of vulnerabilities you want to clean to determine what you want to not copy.